# CSS updating under console but not visually on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I'm currently building an application that compares a bunch of genes in different Cancer Sets and creating a heatmap of sorts to show the highlighted genes. When I want to exclude ALL the cancer sets, I want to have each element in the table to have an opacity of .3 instead of 1. I do this by

```
if(selectedTr.length==0){//no selected Cancers.
    allTr.each(function(){//every line in the table that has the applicable class
        $(this).css({opacity:0.3});
    });
}
```

This is reflected in the element viewer: each tr has an opacity of .3[image]

But visually, the opacity has not changed on the elements, as seen on the picture above. 
On resizing the chrome browser, the css updates to be correct. This issue is also not pervasive on all google chrome browsers: it's working as intended on two of my computers but happens to just not work on my boss's computer (Go figure).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the Chrome version?  Is there an update for it?  Working on other computers means it probably isn't a coding issue.

Comment: @TbWill4321 So I just checked around the office borrowing other people's computer. Both me and my boss's computer are on 46.0.2490.80 (newest version). Seems to work perfectly on windows but seems to be more iffy on the mac version(works half the time) It even worked perfectly on one of my coworker's older version of 46.0.2490.71 .